# How to print multiple items with the same charts? any directions?

Tags: angular, chart.js, angular-chart

I am using angular chartjs. I have user scorecard containing six doughnut & 2 bar charts. It's working fine on print.

I also added directive with the same layout which repeats each (depending on the dynamic list of users selected by web user) user scorecard
(incl. 8 charts for each user)

Now, problem is when i print it does display everything except 8 charts for each user scorecard.

Style: display none to block in print media stylesheet, don't know what's a good approach to show those charts in print version.

Note: all charts are dynamically generated based on the users selected.

Answer (score 0):

I believe i found answer (mentioned below) to my own question... however, still working on it.

maintainaspectRatio: true,
responsive: true

I believe either i need to play with these properties or something else as it somehow distort my current charts so not sure if this will work or not. however, i found a directions to solve it .